# Call selector on static methods from separate class

Tags: objective-c, ios5

let's say I want to create the following gesture recognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * c1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
          initWithTarget:self 
          action:@selector([[MyGestureRecognizer ViewWasClicked1:]]; // error 
[c1 setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[c1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:c1];
```

but I want to call the selector on a separate class. I have the method:

```
+ (void)ViewWasClicked1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {    

    NSLog(@"click1 mouse down");

}
```

in the class MyGestureRecognizer. is it possible to what am I looking for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * c1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
      initWithTarget:[MyGestureRecognizer class]
      action:@selector(ViewWasClicked1:)]; // error
```

Comment: Thanks! for some reason I had an error when I had `self` instead of `[MyGestureRecognizer class]`. I will accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow let's me.

Comment: @TonoNam It may be that ``self`` was being used in an instance method.

For me, using ``self`` inside a class method was not a problem (ie. ``self`` was equivalent to ``[MyClass class]``.

Answer (score 1):

To check for and call static methods, you can do this:

```
SEL staticMethodSelector = @selector(methodName);
if ([[ClassName class] respondsToSelector:staticMethodSelector]) {
    [[ClassName class] performSelector:staticMethodSelector];
}
```